# How to Create a bean validation framework using Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, frameworks

I am having bean AddressBean, which has some properties like addressLine1, city etc.
Before persisting it to DB using AddressBeanService, I am prevalidating it, and after saving, i am post validating it, using preValidate and postValidate function in ValidateAddressService. And all this i am triggering from a AddressBeanHelper class.

```
class AddressBeanHelper{

    AddressBean bean =null;
    AddressBeanHelper(AddressBean bean){
        this.bean=bean;
    }

ValidationService validate=new ValidateAddressService();
    function doStuff(){
        validate.preValidateAddressBean (bean);
        //business logic for AddressBean
        validate.preValidateAddressBean (bean);
    }
}

class ValidateAddressService implements ValidationService <AddressBean>{
    preValidateAddressBean (AddressBean bean){
        //here is the issue
    }
    preValidateAddressBean (AddressBean bean){
        //here is the issue
    }
}
```

I want some framework or trick in spring by which i just need to write generic code in validation functions and externalize my validation rule outside the code itself.
Like a rule engine which can automatically validates each and every property of bean.
currently my application infrastructure is spring/hibernate for server side, jsp/jquery on client side and deployment server is on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one:

http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/12/method-validation-with-hibernate.html

It supports JSR-303, so its a standard. Its very easy to implement, and it supports, custom and some predefined ready to use validators.

You can also find some references here:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-validation-spring-31